# Globbing vs wildcards

Tags: linux, shell, wildcards, terminology

What is the difference between globbing and wildcards, are they two terms for the same thing, or are they different?

Answer (score 7):

[Glob](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) is an alternate name for "Pathname Expansion" as described in the dash (sh) or bash manual (ksh calls it "Filename Expansion"). It is clearly defined in the manuals.

> After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set, bash scans each word for the characters *, ?, and [.  If  one of  these  characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern

[Wildcard](http://www.linfo.org/wildcard.html) is a term for the same concept (one character is used as a pattern standing for several posible characters) but it is not so clearly defined. Wildcard characters are `*` and `?` used in globbing.

> An asterisk (``*'') matches any string of characters.  A question mark matches any single character.

Answer (score 2):

Globbing is a practice of using wildcard characters like **'*'**, **'?'**, and **'$'**, to trigger [pathname expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html). Also, [have a look at the Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) for globbing.

It is usually safe to assume that the shell environment you're working with supports globbing. Unless you're using FTP, or old style DOS, or some kind of shell that doesn't support pathname or Filename expansion. However, those wildcard characters (**'['** is a wildcard in Linux) may have different meanings or operations in different contexts.

Comment: What is `$` in pathname expansion ?

Comment: DOS's shell, or CMD shell doesn't have to support globbing. The commands support them e.g. `DIR *.*`